# laptop screen booting up with lines

Tags: laptop, display, laptop-repair

I truned off my dell taptop the wrong way and then for some reason turned it back on. It started to beep and for about 4 minutes did not come on but continued to beep. When it finally came on it started with a white line and finmally the whole screen was white. It do not see anything on the screen because of the whilt. When I hook up an external moniutor (My TV) I get the desktop screen. Since I was able to get the screen I tried to reboot, but the same whilte screen with the lines coming first came on. Did I damaged the video card or the OS or the mothherboard? The OS is xp pro.

Frank

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably with the laptop screen itself.  If it works with an external monitor then those other things you mentioned are probably working fine.  You'll need someone to replace the display.